# Extract dataLayer object using selenium java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a way to extract the datalayer object from a website via java, using selenium webdriver.
I am trying to automate the content being sent to gtm.
Can someone give me some direction on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make JavaScript calls via WebDriver using `JavascriptExecutor`. The following pulls a String value out of the `dataLayer`:

```
Object x = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("dataLayer[0]['content']['name']");
```

The simplest way to proceed is to first test your JavaScript command manually in your browser console (Chrome Developer Tools, Firebug etc.). Once you know it returns the right value, simply pass to `executeScript()` in your automated test.

The API isn't type-safe so the tricky thing is being careful to cast the returned Object to the right type.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer wasn't working for me and had to do this instead

```
object dataLayer = _driver.ExecuteScript("return dataLayer");
```

Notice the 'return' and removed casting