# Extract pagetype value in datalayer using Selenium IDE or Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to extract the value of pageType in dataLayer with Selenium Java but I received a null value in the variable using this line of code:

`Object X1 = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("dataLayer[0]['pageType']");`

So is there a way to extract that value and put it into a variable or extract it in a simplier way on Selenium IDE?

Edit: I'm running some test on [newhomesource.com](http://newhomesource.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I think I know what the problem is--your script is not returning anything. Try just adding a return,

```
Object X1 = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return dataLayer[0]['pageType']");
```

Comment: I guess the author copy-pasted the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436852/extract-datalayer-object-using-selenium-java  but changed from `['content']['name']` to `['pageType']`. I think the solution provided there should work